# "else not running executing in function(err)

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, node-webkit

I'm trying to console log whether or not my function is running successfully, or it encounters an error.

```
var gui = require('nw.gui'); 
var fs  = require('fs');

onload = function() {
    //console.log(gui.App.argv);
    console.log("onload() is running - from <saveFile.js>")
    var outputPath = gui.App.dataPath + "\\saves\\" + "content.txt";
    var content = "hello world";
    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, JSON.stringify(content), "utf8", function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{ 

                console.log('saved in ' + outputPath);
        }
    });


};
```

it logs the error if encountered, but the else statement never executes.

Comment: perhaps you always get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs.writeFileSync()` is synchronous.  It does not take a callback as an argument.  If there's an error, it throws an exception.  Otherwise, when it returns, it is done.

The function signature from [the node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) is this:

```
fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])
```

You can either switch your existing code to `fs.writeFile()` which is asynchronous and does take a callback or switch to use the right arguments and error handling for `fs.writeFileSync()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped me.